# JPA method signature for binary match in mariaDB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

In my table of mariaDB database, I have a column `name` and It is going to store a person's name in any language.

[image]

There are 2 names `änkür` and `ankur` in table.

If I run below query, it is returning 2 rows

```
select * from table_name where name ='ankur';
```

As I want to return single result I changed my query like:

```
select * from table_name where name = BINARY 'ankur';
```

What is the JPA method signature or alternative solution for the above query?

Comment: Sounds like what you are really after is changing the collation on your schema.

Comment: What type of Collation it should be? `name` column should store any language characters

Comment: Collation, not collection: Basically the "language" rules of your database.